# Keyboard shortcut to clear all breakpoints in Firebug

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, breakpoints

In Firefox, I searching for a keyboard shortcut to clear all breakpoint in Firebug.

Is there any keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

```
Shift+Click on line number -  I found it here;
```

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Keyboard_and_Mouse_Shortcuts

-in the subsection script panel.   Hope this helps

Comment: The OP is asking for how to clear _all_ breakpoints, and how to do it _from keyboard_...

Comment: Anyway, the link shows, there's no such shortcut probably. But how often would one want to clear all breakpoints? That's probably why there's no shortcut :)